# Tensorflow Issue: failed to get compute capability major for device: UNKNOWN ERROR (1); 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-3.8

I have installed tensorflow for CPU on my anaconda. Both tensorflow and keras will be imported correctly, but running them raises error:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
> ----> 2 print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
>
> D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\device_lib.py
> in list_local_devices(session_config)
> 43     serialized_config = session_config.SerializeToString()
> 44   return [
> ---> 45       _convert(s) for s in _pywrap_device_lib.list_devices(serialized_config)
> 46   ]
>
> RuntimeError: failed to get compute capability major for device:
> UNKNOWN ERROR (1); 0

Following are the details of my environment:

Python 3.8.5 (Anaconda) 
Tensorflow 2.6.0 
keras 2.6.0 
Windows 7 64

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of community providing solution here though it is presented in github by @Silvio M.

Steps to follow:

1. Run `cmd` as `administrator`
2. Uninstall `tensorflow` package
3. Delete unnecessary files, this will save lots of space:
   `conda clean --tarballs -packages`
4. Create a new Virtual Environment:
   `conda create --name env-tf python=3.8.5`
5. Download tensorflow whl file, close ALL apps (including browsers), activate the new environment in cmd: `conda activate env-tf`
6. Install the downloaded tensorflow wheel file:
   `pip install f:/ tensorflow_cpu-2.6.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`
7. Check if it has been installed correctly:
   `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"`
8. Install jupyter in the new environment:
   `pip install jupyter pip install jupyter lab`
9. Install python kernel:
   `conda install ipykernel`

For more details you can refer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/51730#issuecomment-912995890)